# How to Create and Insert Unique Id's Based on another column values in single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this

```
Id   Revision_Id        A_Id    A_Name   A_Info
================================================
1           0           111     A1      A_test
2           1           111     A1      A1_info
3           0           222     B1      B1
4           1           222     B1      B1 IINFO
5           2           222     B1      B1 TEST
6           0           333     C1      C1
7           1           333     C1      C1 INFO
```

I need to create table with normal id with auto increment as one column, but I need to add another column `Revison_Id` with increment values starts from 0, 1, 2 and so on, if the table already have record with A_ID data..

As per my data, if my table don't have any same `A_ID` value, then my `Revision_ID` should starts with 0, so my insert need to be as (id(auto increment),0,111,a1,a1 info) like that.

likewise, while insert, if my table already have record in `A_Id` my `Revision_Id` needs to count and increase based on that `A_id`. So to create and insert. How to achieve it?

Comment: *"I tried few answers from stack overflow already"* if you tried, and failed, to implement answers already show us those attempts, explain why they didn't work. telling us you "tried" with no links and no evidence of attempts comes across as a hollow statement (hence why I removed it from the question).

Comment: oh I understand, the thing I tried are mostly failed, so didnt updated here, also I am confused with  dense_rank() , so I didnt posted my tries here.. Apologize for that

Comment: I think that `row_number()` will be easier here than dense_rank

Comment: seems like a good use for a sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com/users/3611669/guidog - first of all , thank you so much for answer, I tried your answer, but don't know ,whats  wrong, its not working exactly as per expectation, finally , I tried different methods ,and found out this  answer bro/sis...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_WITH_REVISIONID       
(@Id int       
)       
AS    
BEGIN
DECLARE @RevisionId int
If EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM TBL_A WHERE A_Id=@Id)
 
BEGIN 
SET @RevisionId = ISNULL((        
      SELECT MAX(Revision_Id) + 1        
      FROM TBL_A  where  A_Id=@Id       
   ), 0) 
INSERT INTO TBL_A
select @RevisionId,
       A.A_ID,
       A.A_Name,
       A.A_Info  from TBL_DATA A where A_Id=@Id
       
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TBL_A
select 0,
       A.A_ID,
       A.A_Name,
       A.A_Info  from TBL_DATA A where A_Id=@Id
       END     
       END
```

and My id is auto increment one.  This one finally fixed my issue, I am sharing here ,so that ,it may help someone in future. Do let me know if there is any concern.

Comment: Do not start your procedure name with `sp_` you can read [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) why

Comment: Also it might be usefull to put this `set nocount on` somewhere in your procedure

Comment: As for your query, is the first column in TBL_A what you call `auto increment` ? If this code works without errors then I am very sure it is not. In sql-server this is called an identity column, and when you assign it a value like in your query you should get an error

Comment: Sorry I mentioned as auto increment, but I used Identity to my Id column,my Id column is auto created one-thats what I was tried to explain there.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correct you have a table with all the information in your sample data, except for the column Revision_ID,
and your goal is to create that column ?

If that is correct you can use `row_number()` like this

```
select d.id,
       d.a_id,
       row_number() over (partition by d.a_id order by d.a_id) - 1 as Revision_ID,
       d.a_name,
       d.a_info
from   data d
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cef956c920b55c02545e5e71b906639c)

If that is not what you are after, please elaborate more what you need

Comment: hi  first of all ,thank you,but,this select query I saw most often, but I m trying to do this Revisoin_ID increment, during the insert based on A_id ,is there any way to do that?

Comment: HAve you looked at the DBFiddle link in the answer ? The last query does an insert into another table like this